# how to disable autoscrolling to top using jquery?

Tags: jquery, scroll

I have placed some links in my webpage to which I have set `click` event handler using jQuery. So when any of these links is clicked a menu will be displayed with `.slideDown()` method but the problem I'm having is that after clicking a link the window gets automatically scrolled to top.

I have't used `scrollTo(0,0)` still the window is getting scrolled. This automatic scrolling to top is not desired and should not happen.

I have tried the following still its not working as desired.

```
document.body.scroll(false);
document.body.scrollTop(0);
```

I have attached 2 images. *image1* is normal webpage and *image2* is the same webpage when `Softwares-2` link is clicked and window is srolled to the top (as can be seen by the scrollbar on the right).

> **Note:** numbers specified in the images are just to show that the window is getting scrolled.

[image: image1]
[image: image2]

Comment: It's definitely not supposed to do that.  Can we see the code?

Answer (score 8):

### Your page is in fact reloading and not scrolling

You have to prevent default link click behaviour (which is: make a request of the resource defined by the `href` attribute value and load response) in your click event by doing this:

```
$("a").click(function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    // display your menu
    // and do what's required
});
```

Usually people also suggest to `return false;` from your handler, but that's not necessary. Still you can do that just before the closing curly brace of the click event handler function.

Comment: Scrolling is disabled but the menu is not getting displayed when the link is clicked. As i have mentioned the menu must also be displayed when the link is clicked with slideDown effect.

Comment: @Karthik: The logic of displying the menu is on you and is beyond the scope of this question. This question is about undesired document scrolling which is solved by the answer provided. The fact is also that we don't have enough data to give any additional info about your menu.

Answer (score 2):

Add an `return false` statement like below.

```
<a href="#" onclick="function();return false;">Link</a>
```

Comment: A correct answer, but better to use the jQuery equivalent, as the OP mentioned he is using it. (See @Robert Koritnik's answer.)

Answer (score 1):

[event.preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) and return false inside your .click handler should fix it up for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

....

return false;
});
```